# Node.js: Error when calling promise's callback function

Tags: node.js, promise

I recently ran in a, for me, strange error. I have this simple function returning
a promise:

```
 create(data) {
            let _self = this;
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                if(_self._validateData(data)) {
                    //is valid, so store in database...
                } else {
                    reject(_self.error);
                }
            });
        }
```

When the data is valid, the data is stored and there is no problem calling the resolve callback. However, when the data isn't valid, I immediately call the reject function. But when I do so I receive an error.

Is it possible that, at the time the process reaches the call of reject, the reject was not set by the calling function? Because when I run following code, it works perfectly:

```
create(data) {
        let _self = this;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            if(_self._validateData(data)) {
                //is valid, so store in database...
            } else {
                setTimeout(function(){reject(_self.error);}, 100);
            }
        });
    }
```

I really want to avoid using this solution. Not only because it looks ugly to me, but also because I am not even sure, if I understand the error.

So any ideas what is wrong here and how can I solve this?

> For everybody facing the same problem:
>   It is not really an error but a "feature" of VS Code Debugger (using v8).
>   See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-node-debug/issues/94) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063281/typescript-promise-rejecting-and-vscode-debugger-behavior) for further information. The issue is called "synchron rejection". Also, I only misinterpreted it as an error. It is not. The debugger just pauses and points out, that there is an synchron rejection
>   I moved on using bluebird promises

Comment: What's the actual error message? Are you certain the error is caused when calling `reject()` and not somewhere else down the promise chain?

Comment: I do not receive any error message with the exception of "Exception:Object". I am not even able to catch it.
And yes, I am sure that it is on calling. I set a breakpoint to the line, where I am calling the function and I reached it. When trying to step into the function, I receive the error

Comment: I highly doubt that there is no additional information regarding that error. Usually an error message or/and stack trace are attached as well. When you say "receive" you mean "getting the error object in some kind of dev tool", right? You should be able to expand its properties to look for additional clues. The above code seems fine to me, so I expect the error to originate elswhere.

Comment: Yes I use VSCode built in Debugger to debug my application. And yes, I can see the stack trace, but on top, there is my function (create) but I cannot find any additional information with the exception of "Exception: Object" which is a plain text.

Comment: In general the given code works. See https://jsfiddle.net/wzjtj6az/5/ So there is some information missing about your setup.

Comment: Yes I think you are right. I just tested it with node (so not with the vs code debugger) and it also works. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that, at the time the process reaches the call of reject, the reject was not set by the calling function?

No, that's not possible. You can reject the promise at any time.

> Because when I [put it in a timeout], it works perfectly

I'll guess that you did not set up a rejection handler (`.catch(…)`) on your promise chain soon enough, and are receiving a "possibly unhandled promise rejection" warning because of that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case, it was a different problem, but thank you for pointing it out

Comment: Oh, VSCode strikes again. Yeah.